# Nissan Primera 2004 CVT - starting issue

Tags: automatic-transmission, ignition, cvt-transmission

For the last 3 days I haven't been able to get my car to start, I can make the ignition crank over but it doesn't want to fire up. I do have an solid engine light going on the dash.

Prior, last I had to replace the fuel tank as it had a a ton of small holes on the underside, tried using quick set metal melding putty but more just kept appearing. There was a bit of rust in the tank.

I'm wondering if any of that rust could have gotten into the fuel line and is blocking the injectors?